# Rails: Search all images that are tagged with a certain tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, tags

I have 3 models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :size, :image

  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :images, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :image
  belongs_to :tag
  attr_accessible :image_id, :tag_id
end
```

Now I have added a few images with corrisponding (prefedined) tags, the relevant code for images/new is:

```
%div.field
  = f.label "Tag"
  %br/
  - for tag in Tag.all
    = check_box_tag "image[tag_ids][]", tag.id, @image.tags.include?(tag)  
    = tag.name
```

How can I now search all images that have a certain tag? I need an @images to display all images that are tagged with one or more predefined tags. I choose these tags with help of checkboxes:

```
%h1
  Search an image
%p
  = form_tag '/tagsearch', :method => 'get' do
    - for tag in Tag.all
      = check_box_tag 'tag_ids[]', tag.id
      = tag.name
    = submit_tag "Search Images"
```

So, the params of this search are now (e.g. a search for all images with the tag_ids 2 and 3):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "tag_ids"=>["2", 
 "3"],
 "commit"=>"Search Images"}
```

What is the best way to perform this kind of image search?

Comment: I think this is good, one thing is make it as "post" method for securiy reason. And also you just write the scope under the Tag model to get all items related with tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
images = Image.includes(:tags).where('tags.id' => params['tag_ids']).all
```

Comment: @shioyama : In this case we will get all the images on the basis of tag_id 2 or tag_id 3 but what will be code if i want only those images that are tagged by both of the tags not either one of them.